# Routing server requests using Apache Vhosts?

Tags: apache-httpd, port-forwarding, apache-virtualhost

I have a multiple server setup that I am having difficulty figuring out the best way to solve a problem.

I have several domain names that are accessed via a single IP address and served from one server (Apache Vhosts) All requests are port forwarded by the router for ports 80 and 443 to that server.

I recently moved one domain from the server to a new server with a different internal IP address (but sharing the same external IP) and I was wondering if it was possible for me to use Apache to pass the request for that domain name to the new server.

I am aware that I can use port forwarding on the router to forward a different port but I don't want my users to have to put in a port number to be able to access the second server.  I really want the changes on the server side to be transparent to users.

Is there a way i can do this filtering by domain name requested ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure a `VirtualHost` as all the others and configure the `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` for this specific domain:

```
Servername www.somedomain.com
ProxyPass / http://internal-web-server/
ProxyPassReverse / http://internal-web-server/
```

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html for details

Comment: Just as a side-note: this only works for protocols Apache does provide proxy modules for. So this can't be done with e.g. SSH.